# Wait for SuckerPunch::Job task completion

Tags: ruby, concurrency, sucker-punch

I try the [Sucker Punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch) gem to process tasks in parallel. But I found no documentation how to wait for its termination.

```
require 'sucker_punch'

class SuckerJob
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  workers 4

  def perform(event)
    sleep(rand(5))
    puts "[#{Thread.current.object_id}] End processing event   #{event}."
  end
end

10.times { |i| SuckerJob.perform_async(i) }
puts "Shutting down ..."
SuckerPunch::Queue.shutdown_all
puts "Shutdown finished, status: #{SuckerPunch::Queue.stats[SuckerJob.name]}"
# [Ugly] call internal method
SuckerPunch::Queue::QUEUES.fetch_or_store(SuckerJob.name).wait_for_termination(10)
puts "Wait finished, status: #{SuckerPunch::Queue.stats[SuckerJob.name]}"
```

It seems, that `SuckerPunch::Queue.shutdown_all()` returns before all tasks are completed.

```
Shutting down ...
[17487240] End processing event   1.
[17488760] End processing event   0.
[17487240] End processing event   4.
[17488760] End processing event   5.
[17486120] End processing event   2.
[17484940] End processing event   3.
[17487240] End processing event   6.
Shutdown finished, status: {"workers"=>{"total"=>3, "busy"=>3, "idle"=>0}, "jobs"=>{"processed"=>7, "failed"=>0, "enqueued"=>0}}
[17484940] End processing event   9.
[17488760] End processing event   7.
[17486120] End processing event   8.
Wait finished, status: {"workers"=>{"total"=>0, "busy"=>0, "idle"=>0}, "jobs"=>{"processed"=>10, "failed"=>0, "enqueued"=>0}}
```

How can I wait until all tasks are completed?

Comment: you can try `SuckerPunch::Counter::Processed.new(@queue).value`

Comment: or check stats you can do `all_stats = SuckerPunch::Queue.stats` then `stats = all_stats[MyJob.to_s]` then stats you get now you can see `stats["jobs"]["processed"]`  now there is `total`, `processed`,`busy`....

Answer (score 3):

You can check status

or check stats you can do

```
all_stats = SuckerPunch::Queue.stats
```

then

```
stats = all_stats[SuckerJob.to_s]
```

then stats you get now you can see

```
stats["jobs"]["processed"]
```

you can check like below

```
  stats["jobs"]["processed"] > 0
  stats["jobs"]["failed"] == 0
   stats["jobs"]["enqueued"] == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
def wait_for_jobs(job_name:, count:, max_seconds: 100)
  Rails.logger.info "Waiting up to #{max_seconds} seconds for #{count} jobs to run"
  wait_time = 0
  while wait_time < max_seconds
    stats = SuckerPunch::Queue.stats[job_name]
    processed = stats['jobs']['processed']
    break unless processed < count

    sleep(1)
    wait_time += 1
  end
  raise StandardError, "Timeout while waiting for #{count} jobs of #{job_name} to have run!" unless wait_time < max_seconds

  Rails.logger.info "#{count} jobs took #{wait_time} seconds to run"
end
```